# How do I find the area in this question?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area bounded by

$$ f(x) = x + 6 $$
$$ g(x) = x^3 $$
$$ h(x) = -\frac{x}{2} $$

*Edit* Fixed simple error on h(x)

I already drew the grew, although it is very hard to really tell where they seem to intersect.

It looks like on the left side of the graph f(x) intersects with h(x) at -12. However going toward the right side of the graph it looks like I'll have to integrate base on f(x) and g(x).

I'm thinking this is a two part integration problem, but I'm unsure of what my bounds should be.

Comment: Can you see the region bounded below and above by two graphs and bounded on left and right by two values?

Comment: Are you sure that the functions are right?

Comment: Originally the functions were: f, g, h, respectively: $y - x = 6$, $ y=x^3$, $2y + x = 0$. I went ahead and brought them to the proper y = mx+b format. I see that f(x) is above h(x), but I also see f(x) is above g(x).

Comment: $y=-\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: So, $y=-x/2$. !!

Comment: @julien Thanks for the graph. "area of region bounded by the curves" sorry I forgot to add that. **EDIT** Thanks Sigur & J.W. Perry, stupid mistake on my end.

Comment: So, now, after fixing the third function, you have to split your region in two others: one for $x$ negative and the other for positive.

Comment: [Now it's clear](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rgve8cqzce) with $y=-x/2$ instead of $y=x/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the graphs to help you. Decompose your region in two parts: one for $-4\leq x\leq 0$ and the other for $0\leq x\leq 2$. Then you just use integrals to compute the area.

First interval (left): below red minus below green

Second interval (right): below red minus below blue

[image]

Comment: So I can take $\int_{-4}^{0} f(x) - h(x) $ + $\int_0^2 f(x) - g(x)$?

Comment: From zero to two, not eight.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, but I fixed it :) Thanks I'll give this a try! Should I be using delta y for this?

Comment: @ConfusingCalc, what do you mean by *using delta y*? Are you asking about the integration variable? you have to integrate with respect to $x$, that is, $dx$.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I was asking because I get confused when I should be integrating in terms of x or y when dealing with area and volume.

Comment: Since you are viewing the regions with $x$ between two constants and $y$ between two functions of $x$ you have to integrate with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Given the [image of the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rgve8cqzce) that @julien posted, we see that the two lines intersect in the second quadrant at $(-4, 2)$. The cubic equation intersects with the line $y = x+6$ in the first quadrant at $(2, 8)$. And the point at which the bounding *lower* curve switches from $y = -\dfrac x2$ to $y = x^3$ is at $x = 0$, and specifically, at the origin. The bounding upper curve remains the same throughout: $y = x+ 6$.

$$\int_{-4}^0 \left((x + 6) + \frac x2\right)\,dx +\int_0^2 ((x + 6) - x^3)\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining amWhy :) the graph on here was a much better presentation than my hand drawn one!

Comment: You're welcome, @ConfusingCalc!